# kernel module compilation error of macro for_each_process

Tags: c, kernel

I am trying to compile a kernel module program to list tasks linearly, such that if you run the command `ps -el` should have the same or similar output. my textbook says:
"In the Linux kernel, the `for_each_process()` macro easily allows iteration over all current tasks in the system:

```c
#include <linux/sched.h>

struct task_struct *task;

for_each_process(task) {
   /* on each iteration task points to the next task */
}
```

so I have the following:

```c
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/sched.h>


int tasks_lister_linear_init(void)
{
  printk(KERN_INFO "Loading module...\n");

  struct task_struct *task;

  for_each_process(task)
  {
    printk(KERN_INFO "pid: %d | pname: %s | state: %ld\n", task->pid, task- 
   >comm, task->state);
  }

  printk(KERN_INFO "Module loaded.\n");
  return 0;
}

void tasks_lister_linear_exit(void)
{
  printk(KERN_INFO "Module removed.\n");
}

module_init(tasks_lister_linear_init);
module_exit(tasks_lister_linear_exit);
```

and when I go to make, I get an error saying

```
implicit declaration of function ‘for_each_process’; did you mean ‘for_each_node’?

expected ‘;’ before ‘{’ token
      |     for_each_process(task) {
      |                           ^~
      |                           ;
```

yet every call to this I have seen has not had a semicolon following. any advice on these errors would be greatly appreciated

Comment: In newer kernels the macro `for_each_process` is defined in [include/linux/sched/signal.h](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.19.8/source/include/linux/sched/signal.h#L543). Probably, you need to `#include <linux/sched/signal.h>` for use that macro. BTW, unless you perfectly know what the error message means, it is better to cite it **exactly**, without rewording. In most cases, an original error message contains sufficient information about "what is going wrong".

Comment: thank you, this was my issue

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using a newer kernel version. In later kernels, the macro for_each_process has been moved to the

```
#include <linux/sched/signal.h>
```

instead of

```
#include <linux/sched.h>
```